# Text replacement in ScintillaNet

Tags: c#, scintilla

I have a ScintillaNet text editing control. I want to replace tabs with 4 x space as the user is typing in the control. I'm not exactly sure where to do this as I'm not very familiar with the control. I have been looking into all the events but nothing seems  fit. Can someone advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the control property ScintillaNET.Indentation, from the GUI or programmatically.

Set IndentWidth=4 (four spaces), TabIndents=true, and UseTabs=false.
This will indent 4 spaces ever time the Tab key is pressed.