# Scintilla tab stops

Tags: c#, scintilla

I want to use spaces instead of tabs.  I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391471/text-replacement-in-scintillanet) that seems to address the issue.  I used the accepted answer, but I'm still having a problem.  If I hit the tab key at the beginning of a line that starts with non-spaces, the tabbing works correctly.  However, if I click anywhere on a line past the `IndentWidth` and hit the tab key, it tabs up to 8 spaces.

E.g.

My `IndentWidth` is 2.  My text is `ABCDEFGHI`.  I'm using periods to represent spaces.

If I click in front of the `A` and hit tab, my text becomes `..ABCDEFGHI` (this is correct)

If I click in front of the `B` and hit tab, my text becomes `A.BCDEFGHI` (this is correct)

If I click in front of the `C` and hit tab, my text becomes `AB......CDEFGHI` (this is NOT correct)

Also, if the cursor is anywhere in the leading spaces of a line, when I hit the tab key, the cursor moves to the first non-space character, and then tabs from there.

E.g.

My `IndentWidth` is 2.  My text is `....WXYZ`.  I'm using periods to represent spaces.

If I click anywhere in the first four spaces and hit tab, the cursor moves to the `W` and then my text becomes `........WXYZ`.  (this is NOT correct)

**UPDATE**

I neglected to mention that I had specifically set the Indentation properties in code as below:

```
scintilla.Indentation.ShowGuides = true;
scintilla.Indentation.IndentWidth = 2;
scintilla.Indentation.TabIndents = true;
scintilla.Indentation.UseTabs = false;
```

I just tried setting the `IndentWidth` to 2 in the property editor at design time, and now it seems to be working correctly.

Conclusion: There is some disjoin between how the editor behaves when the properties are set at design-time vs. run-time.